# Freeimage plugin mirrors RGB arrays if saving in 16-bit

Tags: python, image, numpy, freeimage, scikit-image

I am working with 2D floating-point numpy arrays and saving them as .png files with high precision (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240039/save-numpy-array-as-image-with-high-precision-16-bits-with-scikit-image) for how I came to this point). To do this I use the freeimage plugin, as in that linked question.

This creates a weird behaviour where the images are flipped (both left-right and up-down) if saved to 16-bit. This behaviour happens only for RGB or RGBA images, not for greyscale images. Here is some example code:

```
from skimage import io, img_as_uint, img_as_ubyte
im = np.random.uniform(size=(256, 256))
im[:128, :128] = 1
im = img_as_ubyte(im)
io.use_plugin('freeimage')
io.imsave('test_1.png', im)
```

creates the following picture:

[image: 8 bit greyscale]

when I try to save this in 16 bit, I get the same result (albeit taking 99kb instead of 50, so I know the bitdepth is working).

Now do the same as an RGB image:

```
im = np.random.uniform(size=(256, 256, 3))
im[:128, :128] = 1
im = img_as_ubyte(im)
io.use_plugin('freeimage')
io.imsave('test_1.png', im)
```

The 8-bit result is:

[image: 8 bit rgb]

but doing the following

```
im = img_as_uint(im)
io.use_plugin('freeimage')
io.imsave('test_1.png', im)
```

gives me

[image: 16 bit rgb]

This happens if the array contains an alpha level too.

It can be fixed by including

```
im = np.fliplr(np.flipud(im))
```

before saving. However, it seems to me this is pretty weird behaviour and not very desirable. Any idea why this is happening or whether it is intended? As far as I could see it's not documented.

Comment: I can reproduce this bug in the current dev version of scikit-image. You should raise an issue on their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image).

Comment: Thanks for the response ali_m; I've raised an issue [here](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/1101)

Comment: I can confirm that I see the same broken behavior.  We'll discuss this further on the submitted issue.

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt has fixed the issue in the scikit-image dev version and the issue is closed.