# Can I save a numpy array as a 16-bit image using "normal" (Enthought) python?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there any way to save a numpy array as a 16 bit image (tif, png) using any of the commonly available python packages? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240039/save-numpy-array-as-image-with-high-precision-16-bits-with-scikit-image) is the only way that I could get to work in the past, but I needed to install the FreeImage package, which is a little annoying.

This seems like a pretty basic task, so I would expect that it should be covered by scipy, but scipy.misc.imsave only does 8-bits.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One alternative is to use [pypng](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypng).  You'll still have to install another package, but it is pure Python, so that should be easy.  (There is actually a Cython file in the pypng source, but its use is optional.)

Here's an example of using pypng to write numpy arrays to PNG:

```
import png

import numpy as np

# The following import is just for creating an interesting array
# of data.  It is not necessary for writing a PNG file with PyPNG.
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter


# Make an image in a numpy array for this demonstration.
nrows = 240
ncols = 320
np.random.seed(12345)
x = np.random.randn(nrows, ncols, 3)

# y is our floating point demonstration data.
y = gaussian_filter(x, (16, 16, 0))

# Convert y to 16 bit unsigned integers.
z = (65535*((y - y.min())/y.ptp())).astype(np.uint16)

# Use pypng to write z as a color PNG.
with open('foo_color.png', 'wb') as f:
    writer = png.Writer(width=z.shape[1], height=z.shape[0], bitdepth=16,
                        greyscale=False)
    # Convert z to the Python list of lists expected by
    # the png writer.
    z2list = z.reshape(-1, z.shape[1]*z.shape[2]).tolist()
    writer.write(f, z2list)

# Here's a grayscale example.
zgray = z[:, :, 0]

# Use pypng to write zgray as a grayscale PNG.
with open('foo_gray.png', 'wb') as f:
    writer = png.Writer(width=z.shape[1], height=z.shape[0], bitdepth=16,
                        greyscale=True)
    zgray2list = zgray.tolist()
    writer.write(f, zgray2list)
```

Here's the color output:

[image: foo_color.png]

and here's the grayscale output:

[image: foo_gray.png]

---

*Update*: I created a library called `numpngw` (available on [`PyPI`](https://pypi.org/project/numpngw/) and [`github`](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/numpngw)) that provides a function for writing a numpy array to a PNG file.  The repository has a `setup.py` file for installing it as a package, but the essential code is in a single file, `numpngw.py`, that could be copied to any convenient location.  The only dependency of `numpngw` is numpy.

Here's a script that generates the same 16 bit images as those shown above:

```
import numpy as np
import numpngw

# The following import is just for creating an interesting array
# of data.  It is not necessary for writing a PNG file.
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter


# Make an image in a numpy array for this demonstration.
nrows = 240
ncols = 320
np.random.seed(12345)
x = np.random.randn(nrows, ncols, 3)

# y is our floating point demonstration data.
y = gaussian_filter(x, (16, 16, 0))

# Convert y to 16 bit unsigned integers.
z = (65535*((y - y.min())/y.ptp())).astype(np.uint16)

# Use numpngw to write z as a color PNG.
numpngw.write_png('foo_color.png', z)

# Here's a grayscale example.
zgray = z[:, :, 0]

# Use numpngw to write zgray as a grayscale PNG.
numpngw.write_png('foo_gray.png', zgray)
```

Comment: This works great!! As an added bonus, pyng is one of the "Canopy packages" and while it's not installed by default, it is easily installed with one click from the Canopy program.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, when I run the first example, I receive the following error: `ProtocolError: ProtocolError: Expected 320 values but got 960 value, in row 0`  when writing the file (the last line of the program). I am using `0.0.20`. Might there have been some changes in the api of the package?

Comment: @fabian, I don't know.  You could try creating a github issue at https://github.com/drj11/pypng

Comment: The ProtocolError: ProtocolError: Expected 320 values but got 960 value, in row 0  is due to a change in pngWriter now the default is greyscale=True.
writer = png.Writer(z.shape[1], z.shape[0], bitdepth=16,greyscale=False) solves the problem.

Comment: @GBBL, a very belated "thanks!" for the suggestion.  I have updated the code.

Comment: Have you benchmarked any of these? I have an enormous amount of 16 bit .pngs I need to save and I'm curious which of these methods is the fastest.

Answer (score 6):

This explanation of png and numpngw is very helpful!  But, there is one small "mistake" I thought I should mention.   In the conversion to 16 bit unsigned integers, the y.max() should have been y.min().   For the picture of random colors, it didn't really matter but for a real picture, we need to do it right.  Here's the corrected line of code...

```
z = (65535*((y - y.min())/y.ptp())).astype(np.uint16)
```

Comment: I just noticed this!  Of course, you are correct.  I have updated my answer (and the example at https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/numpngw).

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your 16 bit array to a two channel image (or even 24 bit array to a 3 channel image). Something like this works fine and only numpy is required:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.randint(0, 2 ** 16, (128, 128), dtype=np.uint16)  # 16-bit array
print(arr.min(), arr.max(), arr.dtype)
img_bgr = np.zeros((*arr.shape, 3), np.int)
img_bgr[:, :, 0] = arr // 256
img_bgr[:, :, 1] = arr % 256
cv2.imwrite('arr.png', img_bgr)
# Read image and check if our array is restored without losing precision
img_bgr_read = cv2.imread('arr.png')
B, G, R = np.split(img_bgr_read, [1, 2], 2)
arr_read = (B * 256 + G).astype(np.uint16).squeeze()
print(np.allclose(arr, arr_read), np.max(np.abs(arr_read - arr)))
```

Result:

```
0 65523 uint16
True 0
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, PyPNG is very useful. For Enthought users it can be installed as e.g.:

```
conda install -c eaton-lab pypng
```

I'd use the `from_array` method of the shelf:

```
import png
import numpy as np

bit_depth = 16

my_array = np.ones((800, 800, 3)) 

png.from_array(my_array*2**bit_depth-1, 'RGB;%s'%bit_depth).save('foo.png')
```

Mode uses PIL style format, e.g. 'L', 'LA', 'RGB' or 'RGBA', followed by ';16' or ';8' too set bit depth. If bit depth is omitted, the dtype of the array is used.

Read more [here](https://pythonhosted.org/pypng/png.html).

Answer (score 0):

Created a custom script to do this using just numpy and OpenCV:
(Still feels like a huge overkill though...)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def save_gray_deep_bits(filepath, float_array, bitdepth=16):
    assert bitdepth in [8,16,24]
    arr = np.squeeze(float_array)
    assert len(arr.shape) == 2
    assert '.png' in filepath

    bit_iterations = int(bitdepth/8)
    img_bgr = np.zeros((*arr.shape, 3), np.uint8)
    encoded = np.zeros(arr.shape, np.uint8)

    for i in range(bit_iterations):
        residual = float_array - encoded
        plane_i = (residual*(256**i)).astype(np.uint8)
        img_bgr[:,:,i] = plane_i
        encoded += plane_i

    cv2.imwrite(filepath, img_bgr)
    return img_bgr

def bgr_to_gray_deep_bits(bgr_array, bitdepth=16):
    gray = np.zeros((bgr_array.shape[0], bgr_array.shape[1]), dtype = np.float32)
    for i in range(int(bitdepth/8)):
        gray += bgr_array[:,:,i] / float(256**i)
    return gray

def load_gray_deep_bits(filepath, bitdepth=16):
    bgr_image = cv2.imread('test.png').astype(np.float64)
    gray_reconstructed = bgr_to_gray_deep_bits(bgr_image, bitdepth = bd)
    return gray_reconstructed

bd = 24
gray_image_full_precision = np.random.rand(1024, 1024)*255.
save_gray_deep_bits('test.png', gray_image_full_precision, bitdepth = bd)

# Read image and check if our array is restored without losing precision
bgr_image = cv2.imread('test.png').astype(np.float64)
gray_reconstructed = bgr_to_gray_deep_bits(bgr_image, bitdepth = bd)
avg_residual = np.mean(np.abs(gray_reconstructed - gray_image_full_precision))
print("avg pixel residual: %.3f" %avg_residual)
```