# Create an image with pypng

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, pypng

I'm writing a png image to file using PyPng, the file is created but it's all black when viewed.Here is my code:

```
pngImage = numpy.uint16(numpy.zeros((NUM_ROWS, NUM_COLS)))
#code that assigns the pixels
with open(dataFile + ".png", "wb") as outFile:
        pngWriter = png.Writer(NUM_COLS, NUM_ROWS, greyscale=True, bitdepth=16)
        pngWriter.write(outFile, pngImage)
```

I'm certain that the code that assigns the pixels works fine. I put a break point on the write call and verified that pngImage has nonzero values.
pngImage is a 2D array with integer value for each pixel (not R,G,B tuple).

Am I missing something? Should I be converting the numpy array or something?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696615/can-i-save-a-numpy-array-as-a-16-bit-image-using-normal-enthought-python/25814423#25814423 for an example of creating PNG files with pypng from a numpy array.

Comment: I looked at that but I don't see how it's different from what I'm doing.

Comment: (Ignore my deleted comments and answer.)  I just tried your code, using `pngImage = np.random.randint(0, 65536, size=(NUM_ROWS, NUM_COLS)).astype(np.uint16)`, with both `NUM_ROWS` and `NUM_COLS` set to 16, and it worked for me (using pypng 0.0.17).

Comment: Btw, you can specify the type of the array when creating it instead of casting it after creation: `numpy.zeros((NUM_ROWS, NUM_COLS), dtype=numpy.uint16)`.

Comment: Do you have a (small) example PNG that you could email me at drj@pobox.com?

Note that you're creating a 16-bit PNG. Pixel values should range from 0 to 65535. What's your typical range for your pixel values? If it's 0 to 255, it will be very dark.