# How to save a NumPy array as 16-bit single channel PNG image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have an image in NumPy array format and I want save it to my disk. I used this code:

```
from PIL import Image
....
Image.fromarray(img).save('res.png')
```

But it saved as 8-bit. How can I make it save as 16-bit?

Answer (score 5):

I believe the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25814423/727533 may be what you're looking for. It describes using PyPNG to output a NumPy array as a PNG.