# Saving grayscale image using matplotlib and when loading it has multiple channels

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I am saving images using

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imsave(img_path,img_arr,cmap = 'gray') #shape (512,512)
...
img = plt.imread(img_path)
```

and the img.shape returns a (512,512,4) whereas i expect it to only be (512,512).
I thought maybe all the channels would be the same so I could just pick one but `np.allclose(img[:,:,0],img_arr)`
returns false no matter which index I choose. Printing the images, they are indeed the correct ones I am comparing as they do look almost identical(by eye), but are obviously not exactly identical.

I also tried saving the images with cv2 but that seems to save a black box for some reason. loading them with `cv2.imread(img_path,0)` does return a (512,512) array but something seems to be lost because again, `np.allclose()` tells me they're different.

I wanted to know if there is a good way to save grayscale images? Every method I try seems to convert it to RBG or RGBA which is really annoying. Also, I would like to preserve the dtype (int16) of the image as downsampling it loses important information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot preserve a bit depth of 16 bit when saving images with matplotlib with any of the default colormaps which only have 256 colors (=8 bit).

And in addition, matplotlib converts the pixel values to floats, which may be a source for rounding errors.

In total, matplotlib does not seem to be the optimal tool in case you need to get perfect accuracy.

That being said, even `PIL` does not seem to allow for 16 bit single channel pngs. There is a possible solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696615/can-i-save-a-numpy-array-as-a-16-bit-image-using-normal-enthought-python), but I haven't tested it.

In any case a bulletproof way to save your array without accuracy loss is to save it with numpy, `np.save("arr.npy", im_arr)`.