# possible precision loss when using skimage

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, scikit-image

I tried to follow an example [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240039/save-numpy-array-as-image-with-high-precision-16-bits-with-scikit-image). The code segment is

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io, exposure, img_as_uint, img_as_float
im = np.array([[1., 2.], [3., 4.]], dtype='float64')
im = exposure.rescale_intensity(im, out_range='float')
im = img_as_uint(im)
io.imsave('test_16bit.png', im)
im2 = io.imread('test_16bit.png')
```

However, compiling this program gives the following warning message. What might cause the problem, and how to fix it?

**/devl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scikit_image-0.12.3-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/skimage/util/dtype.py:110: UserWarni: Possible precision loss when converting from float64 to uint16
  "%s to %s" % (dtypeobj_in, dtypeobj))**

Comment: Well ```img_as_uint``` converts from float-based storage to uint-based storage. Of course that's suboptimal! If the input-pixels are integers, you should never start with float64. Not sure, what rescale_intensity will do though (if it can take ints and output ints). And one more thing: *python code is not compiled*. This is a runtime-error.

Comment: So, basically, remove the call to `img_as_uint` and you should be fine.  You can safely ignore the warning, or you can suppress it using `warnings.catch_warnings`.